# "Should we be able to vote on locked posts"

Tags: discussion

"Should we be able to vote on locked posts"

See also the similar post  [Why can't I up-vote a locked question?]

Purpose of posting this:  Original question doesn't allow one to state one thinks one should be able to vote on locked posts as an answer.

Answer (score -20):

My own take on this is that we should be able to vote on any question. Some topics do not get less important with age, and the fact that it is found presumably indicates that it is useful/relevant/interesting to our programming lives.
Furthermore, it seems unfair to the original poster, who could otherwise gain reputation (and possibly privileges, badges, etc.) from the up votes.